# How do I add an Image overlay in Brightcove Smart Player in Full Screen with BEML or JS?

Tags: javascript, html, video, brightcove

**Using BEML**

I've added an `<Image/>` tag to the Brighcove BEML template, from [this documentation](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/beml/beml_rt.dtd.html#Image) on the Brightcove Video Cloud BEML DTD.

The image displays when the video loads, but it disappears when the video goes full screen. Is there anyway to ensure it doesn't do that?

My Code:

```
<Image id="logoOverlay" width=“48” height=“1”4 x="20" y="20" scaleMode="exactFit" source="path/to/image" visible="true"/>
```

**Using Javascript:**

I've heard that you can use a JS API to add a logo, but someone told me that it might not work with Smart Players. Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you must set position: absolute and z-index: 2147483647 in css to image when the video goes full screen.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
includeInLayout="{videoPlayer.fullscreen}"
```